# Environment subfigure - what to do with whitespace

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

So I've made a block of figures using the `subcaption` package. It contains 5 images and follows the following layout:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
                {1.pdf}
                \caption{$1$}
                \label{fig:1}
        \end{subfigure}
        ~
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
                {2.pdf}
                \caption{$2$}
                \label{fig:2}
        \end{subfigure}
        ~
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
                {3.pdf}
                \caption{$3$}
                \label{fig:3}
        \end{subfigure}
        ~
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
                {4.pdf}
                \caption{$4$}
                \label{fig:4}
        \end{subfigure}
        ~
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
                {5.pdf}
                \caption{$5$}
                \label{fig:5}
        \end{subfigure}
        ~  

        \caption{Plots of numbers.}
        \label{fig:numbers} 

\end{figure}
```

My question is: what should I do with the  whitespace? I thought of either putting the `figure` caption there, or centering the last two images so the whitespace is symmetrical. However I don't how to do any of the two. For the latter, I tried inserting an extra `~` before the fourth image but it didn't work-nothing happened.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx but please always try to post complete documents so they can be run locally (otherwise we can not see the spaces you are talking about) or upload a screenshot of your result (use the upload button but remove the `!` as you do not have enough rep yet, but someone will put the `!` back so including the image. Probably you want to use `\hfill` rather than ` ~ ` so the 3 figures on each line are flush left centre and flush right. If you do that and set `\parfillskip` to zero the last two would spread out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Please always post *complete* documents (I had to ask in chat which package you were using as my guess of `subfigure` proved wrong).

The image shows two layouts: the second one from the code as posted to get the first just simply use `\hfill` in all cases not the blank line and `\hfil` construct.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
                {1.pdf}
                \caption{$1$}
                \label{fig:1}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
                {2.pdf}
                \caption{$2$}
                \label{fig:2}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
                {3.pdf}
                \caption{$3$}
                \label{fig:3}
        \end{subfigure}%

        \mbox{}\hfil%
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
                {4.pdf}
                \caption{$4$}
                \label{fig:4}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \hfil
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
                {5.pdf}
                \caption{$5$}
                \label{fig:5}
        \end{subfigure}


        \caption{Plots of numbers.}
        \label{fig:numbers} 

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll be sure to post complete docs in the future.